# Mongoose Select If Contains In Array Field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is my field in schema;

```
...
progress: {
    type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: "users"
},
...
```

In my controller;

```
Post.find({category : cat._id},{_id:0,title:1,slug:1})
```

In mongoose collection I'm saving users id for save their progress. Example collection;

```
progress : [1,2,3,4] // Users
```

I want to find posts with if array contains current user id in progress true, else false. Example code in mysql;

```
select json_contains(progress,2,'$') as prog, title, slug from posts
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly and the schema above is for "Post" model,then all you need is to write it like

```
Post.find({
  progress: someUserId
})
```

In mongodb you can use simply comparison to check if given element is in array.